# Facebook Access Token Expiring with offline access

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token, facebook-oauth

I have an application to manage a users Facebook notifications, the app requests offline_access as well as manage notifications permissions. My logs have been filling up with Facebook errors, I understand that the change password error is going to happen, but what I don't understand is why I am getting these errors:

Facebook Error: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1320012000. The current unix time is 1320191317. 
Facebook Error: (#200) The "manage_notifications" permission is required in order to query the user's notifications.

They are occurring *way* too often to be users just rejecting the permissions and the access tokens that are expiring have expirations of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, offline_access has been removed, now it is possible to get an access_token with a life span of 2 months

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Tokens expires after 2 months how can we extend this time period after 60 days with out user interaction?

Comment: Have a look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ It looks like "Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your app" so the user doesn't need to do anything, but they still need to open your app

Comment: @Luke is it possible if we can get a new access token before expiry time but without user interaction i.e no login again!

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to use the user's token? Once you request offline access, you should "login" with your app to get it's own access token when you want to do something, not use the user's token that you saved. If that is what you are doing.

Scroll down to the part on this page labeled "App Login". That's how you are supposed to do things when user's are not present, not retain and use the user's token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I am using the users token. You're saying I can do everything I need with my app login token even if I'm fetching user data?

Comment: Pretty much. The offline access permission means the user granted you permission to do things without their token. You can use a different issued by Facebook for your app. No need to swap tokens for each user you want to do something with.

Comment: That's incorrect - they should be using the user access token - the user access token with `offline_access` has a long expiry time. It could expire if the user deauthorises the app, changes their password or is locked for security reasons. It'll also invalidate all existing tokens if the App Secret is changed, but otherwise should be OK

Comment: You have to use a user token, using the app token results in:
`{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException"}}`